# Can I pass more than one value for a variable in C?

Tags: c, arrays, variables

Can I pass more than one value for a variable in C?

Follow the example below, this is more or less what i'm saying.

```
int mage;//Normal variable create OK   
int mage{int hp, int mp}
```

I'm learning C now and I want to make a RPG text-based I don't expect to create the best and the most beautiful RPG text-based on the world but it's just for learning.

If nobody understand my question here a resume : Making one variable and pass 2 or more values for this variable.

Comment: look into `struct` and what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C supports structures which allow you to define new types that group values of other types together. A new structure type is declared by using the keyword `struct` and providing a name. The name of the new type is then `struct` followed by that name.

For instance:

```
struct character
{
  int hp;
  int mp;
};

struct character mage = { 42, 4711 };
```

The final line creates a variable called `mage` of type `struct character`, and initializes `mage.hp` to `42` and `mage.mp` to `4711`.

Here's how you would access the field `hp` of the variable `mage`:

```
printf("The HP of the mage is %d\n", mage.hp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, and one more question if i want to acess these values in the future in my code and printf the hp of mage and the mp i just need to do

    printf(mage.mp); //For example? if i use the struct like "unwind" told?

And also sure i have more struct like character custom ( name, class etc.. ) so to do this for a mage i keep going like que example before?

    struct Stats Mage { 40, 100 };
    struct Character Mage { Name, Gold and so on...};

Comment: @RodolfoOlivieri I added code that shows even more clearly how to for example print the HP of the mage, using dot notation. The rest of your comment's new questions are a bit unclear. You need to read more tutorial-type information about C.

Comment: Yeah i'm learning C, and that's is exactly what i want ^~^ the rest i can do for my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

define as:

```
typedef struct {
 int hp;
 int mp;
} mage;
```

use as:

```
mage m;
```

access as:

```
m.hp = 2;
m.mp = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to group multiple values into single variables, the easiest way is using a `struct`.

This allows you to logically group values.

In your example, you could do something like this:

```
struct SAttribute {
    int current;
    int maximum;
};
typedef struct SAttribute Attribute;

struct SCharacter {
    Attribute health;
    Attribute mana;
};
typedef struct SCharacter Character;
```

Note that the `typedef`s are optional and just there to avoid having to write `struct` over and over again.

In your actual program, you can use them like this:

```
Character mage;
mage.health.current = mage.health.maximum = 100;

// damage the mage
mage.health.current -= 5;

// is the mage dead?
if (mage.health.current <= 0)
    printf("The mage is dead.");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure is it possible to pass more than one value to a variable, but I would suggest that you create a *[struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))*

```
typedef struct mage mage;
// define a struct
struct mage {
    int hp;
    int mp;
};

struct mage m = {100, 50};

// now we can access the values
m.hp
m.mp
```